# Is it safe to add yourself to group 82 (_clamav)

Tags: permission, user-account, group

I want to have a similar group id on my host machine (macOS) and virtual machine (docker for mac) to avoid permissions problems. I wanted to create a new user/group with ID 82 but it's already exists – _clamav:_clamav. As I understand it's some kind of antivirus engine. Is it safe to add myself to this group?

Comment: Are you running [clamAV](http://www.clamav.net) on your Mac?

Comment: Well, I think this user/group comes with macOS out of the box, I do not have clamav installed.

Comment: I too have uid 82 assigned to `_clamav` but am not running the software. Given that you are dealing with hard coded values in Alpine Linux, adding yourself is likely the easiest option.

Answer (score 2):

For your purposes, it's best not to add yourself to an existing group.

To discover what groups are on your computer you will find most listed in `/etc/group` - `less /etc/group` will give it to you. You can create a new group by adding it to this list. `man group` will explain the format of this file. I usually create a group with an id from 600 to 699. Apple seems to use ids above 700 for special groups not listed in `/etc/group`.

To discover what groups you are already a member of you can use the `groups` command. To list the ids of the groups you are a member of you can use the command `id -G`.

Comment: The thing is I need this group to have ID 82 because it's hardcoded in Alpine Linux which I use inside of my docker containers. Maybe I could change `_clamav` ID to something else and add a new user/group with ID 82 but it might not be safe.